# Using fit_generator in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am new in using `fit_generator` in Keras, so I tried to write a simple script just to help me understand how it works.

```
X = np.array([[1,2],[10,3],[2,4],[20,5],[30,1],[3,5],[4,6],[7,4],[5,10],[1,7]])
Y = np.array([[2,3],[30,13],[8,6],[100,25],[30,31],[15,8],[24,10],[28,11],[50,15],[7,8]])

def generator(feat,labels):
    i=0
    while (True):
        yield feat[i],labels[i]
        i+=1

model_fnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model_fnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, input_dim=X.shape[1], activation=tf.nn.relu))
model_fnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(Y.shape[1], activation=tf.keras.activations.linear))

nb_epoch = 3000

model_fnn.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
model_fnn.fit_generator(generator(X,Y), steps_per_epoch=10, epochs=nb_epoch, verbose=0)
```

But it gave me error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_2_input to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Could anyone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error seems to be caused by the fact that you need to wrap up every input/label into a Numpy array, which will be the training batch. The code for this generator will be:

```py
def generator(feat,labels):
    i=0
    while (True):
        yield np.array([feat[i]]), np.array([labels[i]])
        i+=1
```

And your error should be solved. You will be training with a batch size 1, as every array passed to the training will contain only 1 object.

But, in order to train using a generator with yield, you need to make sure the cycle will not crash, as it is an infinite loop and you don't have infinite data. This can be achieved using `itertools.cycle`:

```py
import itertools

def generator(feat,labels):
    pairs = [(x, y) for x in feat for y in labels]
    cycle_pairs = itertools.cycle(pairs)
    while (True):
        f, p = next(cycle_pairs)
        return np.array([f]), np.array([p])
```

And, to give one step further in the use of generators using yield, you can give the function a parameter to specify the batch size (as stated in [the comment by PyGirl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60588307/8189455)). This should look a little bit like this:

```py
def generator(feat, labels, batch_size):
    pairs = [(x, y) for x in feat for y in labels]
    cycle_pairs = itertools.cycle(pairs)
    while (True):
        x = []
        y = []
        for _ in range(batch_size):
            f, p = next(cycle_pairs)
            x.append(f)
            y.append(p)
        yield np.array(x), np.array(y)
```

This means, in every step, the generator will yield a Numpy array with `batch_size` elements inside to be trained.

In order to understand more about how to train with `fit_generator` in Keras I would also recommend to read a bit about [the Keras Sequence Util](https://keras.io/utils/) which is safer to use than a generator.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Can the itertools functionality be replaced by for i in range(len(feat))?

Comment: @eng2019 I think so, in the last case (when using a batch size parameter) the code will look a bit nasty tho, but I think It's OK!

Answer (score 1):

I ain't sure but if you will add batch size of 1 then it works i.e expand (2,) -> (1,2)

```
def generator(feat,labels, batch_size):

  samples_per_epoch = feat.shape[0]
  number_of_batches = samples_per_epoch/batch_size
  counter=0

  while 1:

    X_batch = np.array(feat[batch_size*counter:batch_size*(counter+1)]).astype('float32')
    y_batch = np.array(labels[batch_size*counter:batch_size*(counter+1)]).astype('float32')
    counter += 1
    yield X_batch,y_batch

    #restart counter to yeild data in the next epoch as well
    if counter >= number_of_batches:
        counter = 0
```